# How to stop Server-Sent Events

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have a javascript code that listens to a PHP code via Server-Sent Events, it is working well the response is sent from the server trough a loop and when the loop ends the Server-Sent Events stops however a few seconds after the script is again listening. how can I end the Server-Sent Events when the loop from the server side ends too? Thanks.

JS :

```
var sse=new EventSource("data.php");
            sse.onmessage=function(event){
                document.getElementById("map").innerHTML+=event.data;              
            };
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); //indicates that server is aware of server sent events
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');//disable caching of response

$coordinates = [  
   [  
      "20:11",
      33.5731235,
      -7.6433045
   ],
   [  
      "20:11",
      33.5731054,
      -7.6432876
   ],
   [  
      "20:11",
      33.5731644,
      -7.6433304
   ]
];

foreach($coordinates as $c){  
  echo "data: ".json_encode($c)."\n\n";
  ob_get_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636165/how-do-server-sent-events-actually-work/11998868#11998868

Comment: There is nothing about the solution I'm looking for in the link !

Comment: Key line: *"Should it want to, it may terminate the connection and respond with a `204 No Content` next time the client tries to connect.  This will cause the client to stop trying to reconnect."* Please try and read it next time.

Comment: I tried to add Connection: keep-alive but same issue still reconnection after the loop ends, also the link points to a node JS code not PHP

Comment: Keep-Alive has nothing to do with HTTP status codes, what do you mean?

Comment: I added "http_response_code(404);" at the end of the loop but with no success.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a boolean variable `isOpenOnce = false` in your javascript and then in your sse.onopen set `isOpen` to `true` the first time. In the beginning check the flag and close connection if true. This way no need of server side changes.

```
var isOpenOnce = false;
sse.onopen = function() {
 if(isOpenOnce) {
  sse.close();
 }else {
  console.log("Connection to server opened.");
  isOpenOnce = true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi I've added extra to (hopefully fix this)
You have to pass from the server a message to close the connection.
Otherwise when the execution finishes the browser will start with a new connection

***air code***

JS :

```
var sse=new EventSource("data.php");
sse.onmessage=function(event){
    if ('END-OF-STREAM' == event.data) {
        sse.close(); // stop retry
    }
    document.getElementById("map").innerHTML+=event.data;
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); //indicates that server is aware of server sent events
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');//disable caching of response

$coordinates = [
   [
      "20:11",
      33.5731235,
      -7.6433045
   ],
   [
      "20:11",
      33.5731054,
      -7.6432876
   ],
   [
      "20:11",
      33.5731644,
      -7.6433304
   ]
];

foreach($coordinates as $c){
    echo "data: ".json_encode($c)."\n\n";
    ob_get_flush();
    flush();
    sleep( rand ( 1 , 3 ) );
}
echo "data: END-OF-STREAM\n\n"; // Give browser a signal to stop re-opening connection
ob_get_flush();
flush();
sleep(1); // give browser enough time to close connection
```

Comment: No need to send "data: END-IF-STREAM." Just send an event instead, like "event: close" and listen to that with sse.addEventListener('close', fucntion(){ sse.close(); });

Answer (score 0):

the simple and easy way to stop a `sse=new EventSource()` from running or even stop it from loading multiple times is just to check the `window` variable and if it exists, close it.

`if (typeof window.sse !== 'undefined') sse.close();`

done!