# Event source connection can not be kept alive on remote host

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, rest

### The issue

I've got a Rest API in Spring-Boot where i'm listening to an event-source stream from `html` like so:

```js
 eventSource = new EventSource("/api/events/receive", {
        xhrHeaders: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        }
    });
 eventSource.onmessage = function (evt) { ... };
```

> **The EventSource returns 503 after a while!**

---

Works perfectly on localhost but **not** on remote host!

---

### Things i've tried

- add keep-alive on the `@RestController` via `HttpServletResponse` Object

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/events/receive", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
        public Flux<Ambulance> receiveAmbulance(HttpServletResponse resp) {
            
            resp.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
            

            return Flux.create(sink -> {
                ambulanceProcessor.register(sink::next);
            });
        }
```

- add to that template a `keep-alive` header via `@Controller`

```java
@GetMapping("/dashboard")
    public String getResource(Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
            response.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
            return "view";
}
```

### Related posted i've visited

1. [How SSE Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636165/how-do-server-sent-events-actually-work)
2. [SSE Spring Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events)

### 503 After a few seconds

[image]

Note: I've tried almost everything and nothing seems to work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to keep it alive by creating a new `@Service` with this `@Bean`

```java
@Bean
    public void KeepAliveEvt()
    {
        ExecutorService sseMvcExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        sseMvcExecutor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                    ambulanceProcessor.process(new Event());
                    System.out.println("Kept Alive");
                    
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              
            }
        });
    }
```

Basically I'm keeping it alive with a **Dummy Event** every 2 minutes